# Возможно ли изменить анимацию открытию bootstrap burger менью?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bootstrap

Как можно изменить стандартную анимацию открытия бургер  менью в Bootstrap.

То есть чтобы при клике была анимация бургера к примеру вот [**такая**](https://codepen.io/DuudeXX8/pen/ZojOxv)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
      <div class="navbar-nav float-right text-right pr-3">
        <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
        <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, возможно. Вот вам небольшой набросок.

Только учтите, у приведенного в примере бургера - плохо с анимацией. А именно, когда анимация открытия выполняется, повтороное нажатие не запускает анимацию закрытия.

Пример на [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LmgVGp).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $btn = $('.navbar-toggler'),
    $burger = $('.burger'),
    $topLine = $('.burger__line-top'),
    $midLine = $('.burger__line-mid'),
    $menuLine = $('.burger__menu'),
    anim = false;

  var changeClasses = {
    addActive: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        $burger.children().eq(i).removeClass('reverseLine' + (i + 1)).addClass('activeLine' + (i + 1));
      }
    },
    addReverse: function() {
      for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        $burger.children().eq(i).removeClass('activeLine' + (i + 1)).addClass('reverseLine' + (i + 1));
      }
    }
  }

  var timeouts = {
    initial: function(child, Y, rot, scale) {
      $burger.children().eq(child).css('transform', 'translateY(' + Y + 'px) rotate(' + rot + 'deg) scale(' + scale + ',1)');
    },
    afterActive: function() {
      // ES6
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.initial(0, 12, 45, 1.40);
        this.initial(1, -12, -45, 1.40);
        this.initial(2, 35, 0, 1);
        $burger.children().eq(2).css('opacity', '0');
        anim = true;
      }, 2300);
      // With bind()
      // setTimeout(function() {
      //   this.initial(0, 12, 45, 1.40);
      //   this.initial(1, -12, -45, 1.40);
      //   this.initial(2, 35, 0, 1);
      //   $burger.children().eq(2).css('opacity', '0');
      //   anim = true;
      // }.bind(this), 1300);
    },
    beforeReverse: function() {
      setTimeout(() => {
        for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
          this.initial(i, 0, 0, 1);
        }
        $burger.children().eq(2).css('opacity', '1');
        anim = false;
      }, 2300);
    }
  }

  $btn.on('click', function() {
    if (!anim) {
      changeClasses.addActive();
      timeouts.afterActive();
    } else if (anim) {
      changeClasses.addReverse();
      timeouts.beforeReverse();
    }
  });
});
```

```css
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  background-color: #ff6100 !important;
}

.navbar .navbar-toggler {
  width: 71px;
  padding: 0;
  height: 71px;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
}

.activeLine1 {
  transform-origin: left center;
  animation: activeTop 1.3s forwards;
}

@keyframes activeTop {
  20% {
    transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(15px) rotate(48deg) scale(1.4, 1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(7px) rotate(42deg) scale(1.4, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(12px) rotate(45deg) scale(1.4, 1);
  }
}

.activeLine2 {
  transform-origin: right center;
  animation: activeMid 1.3s forwards;
}

@keyframes activeMid {
  20% {
    transform: translateY(-8px) rotate(0deg);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-3px) rotate(-45deg) scale(1.3, 1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-18px) rotate(-45deg) scale(1.4, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(-12px) rotate(-45deg) scale(1.4, 1);
  }
}

.activeLine3 {
  animation: activeMenu 0.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes activeMenu {
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-7px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-7px);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(35px);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

.reverseLine1 {
  transform-origin: left center;
  animation: reverseTop 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes reverseTop {
  15% {
    transform: translateY(3px) rotate(-3deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
  30% {
    transform: translateY(-14px) rotate(-10deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(4px) rotate(5deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-2px) rotate(-3deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.reverseLine2 {
  transform-origin: right center;
  animation: reverseMid 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes reverseMid {
  20% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(13deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(-6px) rotate(-9deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(8px) rotate(6deg) scale(1, 1);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
  }
}

.reverseLine3 {
  transform-origin: right center;
  animation: reverseMenu 1.65s forwards;
}

@keyframes reverseMenu {
  30% {
    transform: translateY(-20px) rotate(0deg) scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  40% {
    transform: translateY(9px) rotate(-10deg) scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  60% {
    transform: translateY(-5px) rotate(5deg) scale(1, 1);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(0deg);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.burger {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 71px;
  height: 71px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.burger__line-top {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #fff;
}

.burger__line-mid {
  margin-top: 17px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #fff;
}

.burger__menu {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.burger__menu p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 0 1px #fff;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo03" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <div class='burger'>
    <div class='burger__line-top'></div>
    <div class='burger__line-mid'></div>
    <div class='burger__menu'>
      <p>MENU</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo03">
    <div class="navbar-nav float-right text-right pr-3">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="#">Pricing</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: спасибо плюсик от меня.А я думал никто не сделает :) codepen пример у вас не работает  кстати

Comment: и кстати этого бага можно избежать поставив таймер анимации меньше :)

Comment: @Demon__ANT Нет, полностью избежать этого бага можно только переделкой js, возможно css. А то может получится такая ситуация, что меню открыто, а гамбургер закрыт. Или наоборот)

Comment: да я потестировал  вы были правы =( баг все еще есть

Comment: @Demon__ANT почему codepen не рабоатет? Он работает, может надо уменьшить окно, что бы гамбургер появился?)

Comment: да уже работает :)